# MVC 3: Passing a Model with a dictionary field to a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am generating the following hml for a grid:

```
<form method="POST" action="home/Edit">
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th> Level </th>
       <th> Cost </th>
       <th> Test </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Level" value='1' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Cost" value='$1.00' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Properties['Test'].Name" value='Passed' /> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[1].Level" value='2' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[1].Cost" value='$2.00' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[1].Properties['Test'].Name" value='Failed' /> </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

My Home controller has a method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PrizelevelsModel model) { ... }
```

And the model is defined as follows:

```
public class PrizelevelsModel
{
    public PrizeLevel[] Prize { get; set; }
}

public class PrizeLevel
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, PrizeLevelProperty> Properties = new Dictionary<string, PrizeLevelProperty>();

    public int Level { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

public class PrizeLevelProperty
{
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I click submit, MVC inflates my model with Prize[2], each Prizelevel in the array has the correct Level and Cost, but the Properties dictionary has 0 elements. How do I get MVC to add to the Properties dictionary of each Prize an element with a key of 'Test' and a value being a new PrizeLevelProperty with the names as set in the form for each Prize?

In other words, when I debug my controller method, I want to see:

```
model.Prize[0].Level == 1  // this works ok
model.Prize[0].Cost == "$1.00"  // and so does this
model.Prize[0].Properties["Test"].Name" == "Passed"  // but not this, instead model.Prize[0].Properties.Count == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty much exactly what you want: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

The default model binder in MVC 3 will bind dictionaries where you specify the Key and Value of the item, so in your case, it would look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="home/Edit">
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th> Level </th>
       <th> Cost </th>
       <th> Test </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Level" value='1' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Cost" value='$1.00' /> </td>
       <td> 
            <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Properties[0].Key" value='Test' />
            <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Properties[0].Value.Name" value='Passed' />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[1].Level" value='2' /> </td>
       <td> <input type='text' name="Prize[1].Cost" value='$2.00' /> </td>
       <td> 
            <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Properties[0].Key" value='Test' />
            <input type='text' name="Prize[0].Properties[0].Value.Name" value='Failed' />
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Though you might make the key hidden depending on what/how you want to implement that.